# htaccess temporary domain name to new domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, dns

Ok, so I have a site that we developed with the temporary domain name like:
http://123.45.67.89/~username

But now that we have switched to the real domain some people are still accessing it with the temporary domain name still and getting errors.

This is a wordpress site that uses the pretty urls and it has some things in the htaccess to speed it up as well.  So what do I add and where?
Here is what I have:

```
            ### REDIRECT FROM IP###

            <IfModule pagespeed_module>
            ModPagespeed on
            </IfModule>

            <ifModule mod_deflate.c>
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
            </ifModule>

            <ifModule mod_expires.c>
            ExpiresActive On
            ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"

            ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
            ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
            ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"

            ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 3600 seconds"
            ExpiresByType application/atom+xml "access plus 3600 seconds"

            ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 15552000 seconds"

            ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 15552000 seconds"
            ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 15552000 seconds"
            ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 15552000 seconds"
            ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 15552000 seconds"
            ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 15552000 seconds"
            ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 15552000 seconds"
            ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 15552000 seconds"
            ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 15552000 seconds"

            ExpiresByType text/x-component "access plus 15552000 seconds"

            ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 15552000 seconds"
            ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 15552000 seconds"
            ExpiresByType font/woff2 "access plus 15552000 seconds"
            ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 15552000 seconds"
            ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 15552000 seconds"
            ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 15552000 seconds"

            ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 15552000 seconds"
            ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 15552000 seconds"
            ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 15552000 seconds"
            ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 15552000 seconds"
            ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 15552000 seconds"

            ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 15552000 seconds"
            ExpiresByType application/octet-stream "access plus 15552000 seconds"
            </ifModule>

            <ifModule mod_headers.c>
            <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
            Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=15552000"
            Header set Pragma "public"
            </filesMatch>
            <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
            Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=15552000"
            Header set Pragma "public"
            </filesMatch>
            <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
            Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=15552000"
            Header set Pragma "public"
            </filesMatch>

            Header set X-Powered-By "WP Optimize By xTraffic/4.1.11"
            Header set Server "WP Optimize By xTraffic/4.1.11"
            </ifModule>

            <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /

            AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*(wp-includes|wp-content|wp-admin|\.php).*$
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
            RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$
            RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*(2.0\ MMP|240x320|400X240|AvantGo|BlackBerry|Blazer|Cellphone|Danger|DoCoMo|Elaine/3.0|EudoraWeb|Googlebot-Mobile|hiptop|IEMobile|KYOCERA/WX310K|LG/U990|MIDP-2.|MMEF20|MOT-V|NetFront|Newt|Nintendo\ Wii|Nitro|Nokia|Opera\ Mini|Palm|PlayStation\ Portable|portalmmm|Proxinet|ProxiNet|SHARP-TQ-GX10|SHG-i900|Small|SonyEricsson|Symbian\ OS|SymbianOS|TS21i-10|UP.Browser|UP.Link|webOS|Windows\ CE|WinWAP|YahooSeeker/M1A1-R2D2|iPhone|iPod|Android|BlackBerry9530|LG-TU915\ Obigo|LGE\ VX|webOS|Nokia5800).* [NC]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_user_agent} !^(w3c\ |w3c-|acs-|alav|alca|amoi|audi|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-|dang|doco|eric|hipt|htc_|inno|ipaq|ipod|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-|lg/u|maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|palm|pana|pant|phil|play|port|prox|qwap|sage|sams|sany|sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo|teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|wap-|wapa|wapi|wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda\ |xda-).* [NC]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge\ |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera\ m(ob|in)i|palm(\ os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows\ ce|xda|xiino [NC,OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a\ wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r\ |s\ )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1\ u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp(\ i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-|\ |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac(\ |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt(\ |\/)|klon|kpt\ |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg(\ g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-|\ |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v\ )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v\ )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-|\ )|webc|whit|wi(g\ |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-) [NC]
            RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
            RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/wp-optimize-by-xtraffic-optimize-cache/data/%{SERVER_NAME}/https/pc/$1/data/index.html -f
            RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/wp-optimize-by-xtraffic-optimize-cache/data/%{SERVER_NAME}/https/pc/$1/data/index.html" [L]

            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*(wp-includes|wp-content|wp-admin|\.php).*$
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
            RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$
            RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*(2.0\ MMP|240x320|400X240|AvantGo|BlackBerry|Blazer|Cellphone|Danger|DoCoMo|Elaine/3.0|EudoraWeb|Googlebot-Mobile|hiptop|IEMobile|KYOCERA/WX310K|LG/U990|MIDP-2.|MMEF20|MOT-V|NetFront|Newt|Nintendo\ Wii|Nitro|Nokia|Opera\ Mini|Palm|PlayStation\ Portable|portalmmm|Proxinet|ProxiNet|SHARP-TQ-GX10|SHG-i900|Small|SonyEricsson|Symbian\ OS|SymbianOS|TS21i-10|UP.Browser|UP.Link|webOS|Windows\ CE|WinWAP|YahooSeeker/M1A1-R2D2|iPhone|iPod|Android|BlackBerry9530|LG-TU915\ Obigo|LGE\ VX|webOS|Nokia5800).* [NC]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_user_agent} !^(w3c\ |w3c-|acs-|alav|alca|amoi|audi|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-|dang|doco|eric|hipt|htc_|inno|ipaq|ipod|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-|lg/u|maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|palm|pana|pant|phil|play|port|prox|qwap|sage|sams|sany|sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo|teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|wap-|wapa|wapi|wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda\ |xda-).* [NC]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge\ |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera\ m(ob|in)i|palm(\ os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows\ ce|xda|xiino [NC,OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a\ wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r\ |s\ )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1\ u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp(\ i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-|\ |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac(\ |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt(\ |\/)|klon|kpt\ |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg(\ g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-|\ |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v\ )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v\ )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-|\ )|webc|whit|wi(g\ |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-) [NC]
            RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
            RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/wp-optimize-by-xtraffic-optimize-cache/data/%{SERVER_NAME}/http/pc/$1/data/index.html -f
            RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/wp-optimize-by-xtraffic-optimize-cache/data/%{SERVER_NAME}/http/pc/$1/data/index.html" [L]
            </IfModule>



            # BEGIN WordPress
            <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
            </IfModule>



            # END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention whether you want to preserve the actual path to the requested URL (or indeed that you have 1 to 1 mappings of URLS across the servers. I'm assuming you do as you mention simply wanting to redirect the domain. so something like this should do the trick:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} *!^www*.newdomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You would place this after your **RewriteEngine On** call

Comment: Thanks for your help and yes I want to maintain the actual path.  I tried your suggestion and instead of getting a wordpress page not found message I get a 500 server error.

Comment: I think it was just missing the ^ after the RewriteRule and it seems to work now.  Thanks